# Erro ao gerar relatório pdf(Jasper)

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Então galera quando executo meu programa ele me traz o seguinte erro(E sim o arquivo está no local):

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brenno.mello\Documents\Projeto%20SPED\coffeepot-br-sped-fiscal\target\classes\relatorio\RelatorioNcmInexistente.jasper
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:127)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:116)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:119)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(JasperFillManager.java:680)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.relatorio.Relatorio.gerarRelatorio(Relatorio.java:83)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.control.ControlImportacaoEscrituracao.importarEscrituracao(ControlImportacaoEscrituracao.java:137)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.control.ControlPrincipal.importarArquivo(ControlPrincipal.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1767)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3399)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3767)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$276/423496581.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brenno.mello\Documents\Projeto%20SPED\coffeepot-br-sped-fiscal\target\classes\relatorio\RelatorioNcmInexistente.jasper
    ... 50 more
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brenno.mello\Documents\Projeto%20SPED\coffeepot-br-sped-fiscal\target\classes\relatorio\SubIncorreta.jasper
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:127)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:116)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:119)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(JasperFillManager.java:680)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.relatorio.Relatorio.gerarRelatorio(Relatorio.java:83)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.control.ControlImportacaoEscrituracao.importarEscrituracao(ControlImportacaoEscrituracao.java:138)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.control.ControlPrincipal.importarArquivo(ControlPrincipal.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1767)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3399)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3767)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$276/423496581.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brenno.mello\Documents\Projeto%20SPED\coffeepot-br-sped-fiscal\target\classes\relatorio\SubIncorreta.jasper
    ... 50 more
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brenno.mello\Documents\Projeto%20SPED\coffeepot-br-sped-fiscal\target\classes\relatorio\SubAproveitamentoIndevidoICMS.jasper
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:127)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:116)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:119)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(JasperFillManager.java:680)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.relatorio.Relatorio.gerarRelatorio(Relatorio.java:83)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.control.ControlImportacaoEscrituracao.importarEscrituracao(ControlImportacaoEscrituracao.java:139)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.control.ControlPrincipal.importarArquivo(ControlPrincipal.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1767)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3399)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3767)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$276/423496581.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brenno.mello\Documents\Projeto%20SPED\coffeepot-br-sped-fiscal\target\classes\relatorio\SubAproveitamentoIndevidoICMS.jasper
    ... 50 more
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brenno.mello\Documents\Projeto%20SPED\coffeepot-br-sped-fiscal\target\classes\relatorio\NcmIsentaCstDiferente40.jasper
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:127)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:116)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:119)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(JasperFillManager.java:680)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.relatorio.Relatorio.gerarRelatorio(Relatorio.java:83)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.control.ControlImportacaoEscrituracao.importarEscrituracao(ControlImportacaoEscrituracao.java:140)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.control.ControlPrincipal.importarArquivo(ControlPrincipal.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1767)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3399)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3767)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$276/423496581.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brenno.mello\Documents\Projeto%20SPED\coffeepot-br-sped-fiscal\target\classes\relatorio\NcmIsentaCstDiferente40.jasper
    ... 50 more
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brenno.mello\Documents\Projeto%20SPED\coffeepot-br-sped-fiscal\target\classes\relatorio\NcmTributadaCst40.jasper
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:127)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:116)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:119)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(JasperFillManager.java:680)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.relatorio.Relatorio.gerarRelatorio(Relatorio.java:83)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.control.ControlImportacaoEscrituracao.importarEscrituracao(ControlImportacaoEscrituracao.java:141)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.control.ControlPrincipal.importarArquivo(ControlPrincipal.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1767)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3399)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3767)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$276/423496581.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brenno.mello\Documents\Projeto%20SPED\coffeepot-br-sped-fiscal\target\classes\relatorio\NcmTributadaCst40.jasper
    ... 50 more
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brenno.mello\Documents\Projeto%20SPED\coffeepot-br-sped-fiscal\target\classes\relatorio\NcmSubstituicaoCstIncorreta.jasper
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:127)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:116)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:119)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(JasperFillManager.java:680)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.relatorio.Relatorio.gerarRelatorio(Relatorio.java:83)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.control.ControlImportacaoEscrituracao.importarEscrituracao(ControlImportacaoEscrituracao.java:142)
    at coffeepot.br.sped.fiscal.control.ControlPrincipal.importarArquivo(ControlPrincipal.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1767)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3399)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3767)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$276/423496581.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
```

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Olá William, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Apesar de nesse caso específico o problema ter ficado claro pelo stack trace, é sempre uma boa ideia compartilhar um enxerto de código que reproduza o problema, bem como informações necessárias para reproduzi-lo. Para mais informações de uma olhada em [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Obrigado cara, realmente teria sido mais simples fazer deste jeito porém peguei este projeto recentemente( 4 dias especificamente) então ainda estou analisando o código, mas agradeço a consideração.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brenno.mello\Documents\Projeto%20SPED\coffeepot-br-sped-fiscal\target\classes\relatorio\RelatorioNcmInexistente.jasper
```

O seu relatório compilado (arquivo `.jasper`) não existe ou não está na pasta esperada.

### Update

Foi um problema com o espaço no caminho que está sendo *url encoded* pelo Jasper (`%20`).

Comment: O pior é que ele exite e está nessa mesma pasta isso é que está fazendo eu me descabelar rsrsrsrsrs, ja tentei passar o caminho absoluto porém o mesmo erro persiste, vou passar um pente fino no código e posto de forma mais detalhada como você falou, desde já obrigado.

Comment: Estou desconfiado desse espaço. Tente em uma pasta sem espaços. Fora isso só olhando o código mesmo. Abraços.

Comment: Fiz como você falou e retirei o espaço entre "Projeto SPED" e funcionou! muito obrigado!, gostaria de saber por que a sua dúvida com o espaço para entender melhor a resolução do problema. Até mais.

Comment: Foi no chutômetro mesmo... `Projeto%20SPED` está passando por [url encoding](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_por_cento), o Windows não costuma lidar bem com isso.

Comment: Que bom que foi gol rsrsrs, obrigrado e até mais.

Answer (score 0):

Quando eu tive que trabalhar com jasper tive alguns problemas com o caminho, mesmo especificando o caminho correto ele não conseguia pega-lo, então eu acabei utilizando o caminho relativo a raiz do meu projeto, que no caso é o src, isto por que eu desenvolvi no netbeans, você deve ver qual é o seu caminho raiz e pegar apartir dele. da uma olhada na minha chamada:

```
JRResultSetDataSource relatResult = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);

JasperPrint jpPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                "src/cob/plus/rel/ClienteDemonstrativo.jasper",
                new HashMap(), relatResult);

JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jpPrint, false);
jv.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Então cara, eu tentei utilizar o caminho como você falou(src) e o erro desta vez foi o nullpointer também já tentei usar o caminho absoluto(apartir do C:) porém também é retornado nullpointer, vou analisar o código melhor e postar de forma mais detalhada, desde já obrigado.